Authelia & HAProxy session issue
In Authelia when either the "inactivity or the "expiration" time has been reached, the protected web app breaks, most of the web apps are powered by JavaScript so it's a matter of client-side caching.
The only way for this to work is when you hard refresh the page and then you will be redirected back to Authelia to sign back in.
Example screenshot from Checkmk
I haven't found a solution so far
